# How do I find out what apps are in iTunes and not on my iPhone, and vice versa?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications

I want to find out:

- What apps are in my iTunes Library that are not on my iPhone.
- What apps are on my iPhone that are not in my iTunes Library.

Is there any way (either in Windows or using third-party software) to find out this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For apps that are in your library [associated to an account] but not on your phone, go to iOS App Store > Updates > Purchased, then tap the "Not on this Phone" tab.

For app that are on your phone, but not in your library. Connect your phone to you computer, load iTunes, select the phone from the connected devices list and go to the apps section. Each app that is installed on your phone will be missing the Install/update button next to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out the "Not on this iPhone" tab also shows apps that are in the Cloud but not in my iTunes Library (because I installed them and deleted them from my iPhone before syncing with iTunes). Also, I now don't think it's possible for an app to be on the iPhone and not in the iTunes Library after you sync, because syncing will transfer all new/updated apps on the iPhone to the iTunes Library. But looking at the Apps section of the iPhone in iTunes is still helpful because it has an "Install" button next to those apps in your iTunes Library that aren't on your iPhone.